# How to combine multiple observable together based on one outer observable?

Tags: rxjs

I am still very new to RxJs so bear with me.

**I have** an observable that emits a JSON document as it changes

That document includes a list of email addresses

Each of those email addresses have a profile associated to it that I can look up with an observable

**I would like to end up with** an observable that emits an array of profiles whenever there is a change to the list of email addresses in the original document.

**I have tried** to use `switchMap()` in combination with `combineLatest()`, however it doesn't work for when the list of email addresses is empty. As a fix I introduced a check for that and then return an `of([])`.

```
documentObservable.pipe(
  filter(document =>{
    return hasEmailListChanged(document.emails);
  }),
  switchMap(document => {
    if (!document.emails.length) {
      return of([]);
    }
    const profileObservables = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < document.emails.length; i++) {
      profileObservables[i] = getProfile(document.emails[i])
    }
    return combineLatest(profileObservables);
  })
);
```

This worked well until I got multiple subscribers to the observable. Then it suddenly only notified the first subscriber when the list was empty. I think it is because `of([])` completes after having emitted the empty array.

Additionally I think the creation of multiple observables inside the document observable is bad, and it would be better to use something like `combineAll()` instead.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by multiple subscribers to the observable? Do you mean returning documentObservable multiple times or..?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Even when you're making multiple subscriptions all of them should receive all notifications.